# rails js require in js.coffee file Sprocket::FileNotFound

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, sprockets

i'm using gem bootstrap-timepicker-rails.
I met this error

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound (couldn't find file 'bootstrap-timepicker'
```

in production server but i added to precompile list..

**in layout..**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'ceo/ceo', @js_controller_action #( ceo/service/class_new.js) %>
```

**ceo/service/class_new.js.coffee**

```
//=(or #=) require bootstrap-timepicker
```

**application.rb**

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "lib")
config.assets.precompile += ['ceo/*', 'bootstrap-timpicker.js', 'blueimp-gallery-all.js'...]
```

**public/assets (deploy asset path in server)**

```
...
ceo/service/class_new-MD5HASH.js
...
bootstrap-timepicker-MD5HASH.js
blueimp-gallery-all-MD5HASH.js
...
```

if I request this url, error page open and in server log..

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound (couldn't find file 'bootstrap-timepicker' ...) ~~class_new.js.coffee:2)
```

However **blueimp-gallery-all in blueimp-gallery-rails gem works well**

in @js_controller_action (.js.coffee)

```
//=require blueimp-gallery-all
```

blueimp function works well. no error.

why blueimp works and bootstrap-timepicker not works ?

Comment: Maybe, you forget to restart your app after adding a new gem?

Comment: No, app is restarted whenever deployed

Comment: for now.. I add require to .js (ceo/ceo.js) file not .js.coffee (@controller.js.coffee). this works. why not works if add to .js.coffee...
thinking about difference of two files.. in ceo/ceo.js is only require codes and in @controllr_action.js.coffee is require codes with other coffeescript code.